3D visualizing rank-1 decomposition of a matrix?
I'm looking for an automated way visualize a matrix rank-1 decomposition in a 3d way
I was thinking of rank-3 decomposition having slices, where area of each slice is proportional to the magnitude:

A = {{1., 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}};
{U, \[CapitalSigma], V} = SingularValueDecomposition[A];
r = Length[Diagonal[\[CapitalSigma]]];
rank1Matrices = 
  Table[\[CapitalSigma][[i, i]]*
    Outer[Times, U[[All, i]], V[[All, i]]], {i, r}];
Assert[A == Total@rank1Matrices];
Print["Rank-1 magnitudes: ", Norm /@ rank1Matrices]


What is rank-3 decomposition? Could you please explain a little more about the meaning of this picture? If matrix $A$ has $n$ singular values, there are $n$ slices?

@A.Kato yes, rank 1 decomposition turns it into sum of rank 1 matrices, which can be sorted by norm in decreasing order

Clear["Global`*"];
A = N[RandomInteger[{-10, 10}, {5, 7}]];
A // MatrixForm


{U, \[CapitalSigma], V} = SingularValueDecomposition[A];
r = Length[Diagonal[\[CapitalSigma]]];
rank1Matrices = 
  Table[\[CapitalSigma][[i, i]]*
    Outer[Times, U[[All, i]], V[[All, i]]], {i, r}];
Assert[A == Total@rank1Matrices];
Print["Rank-1 magnitudes: ", Norm /@ rank1Matrices]


sidelengths = Sqrt[Norm[#]] & /@ rank1Matrices;
Graphics3D[
 MapIndexed[Cuboid[{#2[[1]]-1, -#1, -#1}, {#2[[1]], #1, #1}] &, 
  sidelengths], Boxed -> False]



+1 Very nice, @A. Kato!
